# Update multiple Named Ranges created by Dynamic Source using Spill

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges, spill-range

In Excel 365, currently I manually update multiple named ranges based on a dynamic header row, with dynamic values under each header. I hoping someone can help me with using VBA code to update the names and ranges all together based on the current data/table.

The goal is to have a drop down list with the relevant `Units` values, without blanks or duplicates, for each Item.

The source data comes from an external workbook that is updated weekly. The data is in columns of `Item` and `Units`, but there is often multiple instances of each `Item` and `Units` and each week there may be new Items or some removed, same with the associated `Units` values. The source is as per below example:

| ITEM | UNITS |
| --- | --- |
| AA 120 | 100 |
| AA 120 | 100 |
| AA 120 | 150 |
| AA 60 | 350 |
| BB 200 | 36 |
| BB 200 | 30 |
| BB 200 | 30 |
| SH 1001 | 55 |
| SH 1001 | 55 |

The unique headers are pulled using the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$600, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($K$2:K2, $B$4:$B$600), 0)),"")
```

The following formula is in the row below the headers, to pull the unique values for each header

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($C$4:$C$600,$B$4:$B$600=L2))
```

The resulting table is as per below example:

| AA 120 | AA 60 | BB 200 | SH 1001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 350 | 36 | 55 |
| 150 |  | 30 |  |

Currently I have highlight all the headers and the row below and select `Create from Selection` under `Defined Names` and select `Top row`. This creates named ranges that refer to the cell below each header. I then edit each range that the name refers to, by adding `#` at the end, so it refers to the spilled data, as it is a dynamic range.

e.g. Update the named range reference for `AA_120` from `=SHEET1!$L$3` to `=SHEET1!$L$3#`

I do this one by one for 100+ named ranges. Any tips or help to make this more efficient?

oh and the formula I'm using for the source of the Data Validation is `=INDIRECT(C7)` where `C7` is the Item/named range. This all works well...

TIA

EDIT:
I worked out some VBA code to add the `#` at the end of the referred range. The range for all Named Ranges starts on row 3, so this worked to update all relevant ranges at once...

```
Sub RangeRename()

Dim n As Name
    For Each n In Names
        If Right(n.RefersTo, 1) = "3" Then n.RefersTo = n.RefersTo & "#"
    Next n
End Sub
```

Would still really appreciate it if someone could improve on my VBA, to update all the ranges from when the source data is updated. Currently I delete all named ranges in the `Name Manager`, then select the 2 rows with all the updated `Item` and `Units` data. Then `Create from Selection` under `Defined Names` and select `Top row`. Then I run my macro. But if the Macro could do all above, that would be great. The difficulty I see if that the amount of `Items` and corresponding `Units` vary as it is dynamic. Plus there are 3 data sources on 3 different sheets, all rows 2&3 but columns start at L, N & T for the 3 sheets.

What I have worked out will work for me, but if anyone can improve on my code, I'd be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is wanting to achieve the same thing.

I used a filter to create the column of items, then `TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(G:G,B:B=T7` for the rows of unit options next to each item.

For the VBA I added the following to a module

```
Function xDAV(c As Range) As Range
Dim r As Range
 
With Sheets("LookUpList").Columns("T:T") 'Items
    
    Set r = .Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    'Units are in col U
    'col U is 1 column to the right from col T
    n = 1 'change to suit
    
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set f = r.Offset(, n)
            If f.Offset(, 1) = "" Then
                Set xDAV = f 'single cell or blank cell
            Else
                rc = f.End(xlToRight).Column 'get last column with data
                Set xDAV = f.Resize(, rc + 1 - f.Column)
            End If
    End If

End With

End Function
```

Then in the data validation I entered `=toXDAV` in the source field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do...but can't you get the info you want with a simple pivot table?  I imagine there are advanced tricks you can apply to that to get to the formatting you want...

But using current Excel formulas, I think I got what you want by doing this:

1. I pasted your source data into a worksheet (A1:B10) and made it into
   a table (Control+T), selecting 'My table has headers' option.  (I think it's better to use a table but it's certainly possible to tweak the formulas below if you don't want to.)

   [image: source data]
2. I picked another cell on the same or another sheet--let's say E2--and entered `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Table1[ITEM]))`.  This gives a horizontal spill of unique items.
3. In the cell immediately below that (ie, E3) I entered `=IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[[UNITS]:[UNITS]],Table1[[ITEM]:[ITEM]]=D15))),"")`.  (You need to repeat the bracketed column names like this if you want to drag things horizontally, which we do.)  If you don't need/want to sort the Units in the columns we're going to create, you can leave that part of the formula out.
4. I dragged that cell horizontally to the left, going way beyond you need it right now (in case any new Items appear in your list).  The `IFERROR` in the formula will keep the table looking clean on the right-most columns where no data currently appear. If/when you add more rows to your source data table, the spilled formulas will adjust accordingly, so I think your worry about dynamic sources is taken care of.

Results shown below.  Maybe there's a way to devise a single formula that when put into E3 will spill into a 2-D array, so you don't even need to drag things...but I'll leave that to someone else.

[image: resulting table]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had actually already done that part as mentioned, I was trying to use VBA to create named ranges for data validation from a dynamic source. I ended up using a UDF to define the named range and using that name for the data validation.